# iOS initWithNibName for UIView

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, uiview

Is it possible to implement initWithNubName for a custom class that extends UIView.

Example:

.h

```
@interface UIPullerView : UIView
{
}
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil;
```

.m

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    NSBundle *bundle = nibBundleOrNil==nil ? [NSBundle mainBundle] : nibBundleOrNil;
    NSString *nibName = nibNameOrNil==nil ? @"UIPullerView" : nibNameOrNil;
    if (self == [[bundle loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]) 
    {
        NSLog(@"yes, the same class");
    }
    return self;
}
```

some controller class calls this

```
UIPullerView *puller = [[UIPullerView alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
```

This is not a working example because I don't set the first XIB object to self. If I would I would loos a reference to the main class right? So I would like to add a method that would read XIB file and replicate the object from XIB into self. I don't want to use UIViewController but the UIView  so no additional views should be added to main view.

Se also how I set the XIB:

[image]

I would do

```
- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
...
    self = [[bundle loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0]
    return self;
}
```

but this isn't right true?

Is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I just want to add initWithNibName method to my class that extends UIView (not UIViewController).

Comment: I don't think so. The method "initWithNibName" is defined in the class UIViewController in the SDK and not in UIView so you cannot override that method in your class which extends UIView.

Comment: This should be similar to UITableViewCell.

Answer (score 3):

To get around the issue of assigning self and losing the main class reference, I wonder if you should do it similarly as with loading a `UITableViewCell` from a NIB:

```
  [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"MyTableCell" owner:self options:nil];
  cell = myTableCell;
  self.myTableCell = nil;
```

and set the class that is doing this as the owner of the NIB.

Of course, if you're instantiating your `UIPullerView` in multiple, different, places then that last part gets tricky...

Comment: hum... but how can I set the first view (from loadNibNamed array) to be the owner?

Comment: You would have this code in the method where you instantiate UIPullerView. So that class would be the owner.

Comment: well yeah... I know, it would be very easy using UIViewController but UIView with nib file as same class is tricky ...

Answer (score 1):

Create a `ExampleView.xib`

Create `ExampleView.h` and `ExampleView.m`

```
 @interface ExampleView : UIView

 @end
```

In the `ExampleView.xib`'s Identity Inspector, set Custom Class to `ExampleView`

[image]

In `Example.m`, add `awakeFromNib`

```
- (void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib];
 // [self whateverInits];
}
```

which will be executed whenever the view is loaded, say, by:

```
NSArray *objects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ExampleView" owner:self options:nil];
ExampleView *exampleView = [objects firstObject];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
- (instancetype)initWithNib {
    NSString *nibName = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:object_getClassName(self)];
    return [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:nibName owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```